# persist data in docker - persist websphere applications in docker

Tags: docker, websphere, docker-volume

I'm a beginner with docker...

I'm able to run a docker image with websphere and deploy a simple java application in it (just to test it).

`docker run --name test -h test -p 9043:9043 -p 9443:9443 -d  ibmcom/websphere-traditional`

the container stars correctly so i can deploy my application through the whebsphere console.

When i stop the container, obviously, the data that i've putted in the websphere are lost.

```
docker stop test   
docker rm test
```

with `docker stop test` only, the data are not lost, but i need to switch off the docker machine at all(`docker-machine stop`, mine is a developer enviroment).

So i've tried to start the container with a volume....

`docker run --name test -h test -p 9043:9043 -p 9443:9443 -d --mount source=myfirstvolume,destination=/myfirstvolumemounted ibmcom/websphere-traditional`

bui i imagine, this isn't enough to permit the container to keep the application that i've installed in

Answer (score 0):

When you `docker run` a container, you are creating an instance of that container from the specified image and starting it.  Once you've created the container, you can simply `docker start` and `docker stop` the WebSphere App Server container without losing any of the WAS data that you've saved to the configuration repository, just as if you were running WAS outside a container.  If you install an application to WAS and save the configuration, that application will still be installed after stopping and restarting the container.

Comment: any chance to save the configuration in a long persistent way? just to develop purposes? turn off the machine, turn on the machine... and so on

Comment: The WAS configuration repository is "a long persistent way" to use your terms.  By default, the config repo resides on disk and is thus immune to "turn off the machine, turn on the machine".  Is this not the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: no, when i switch off the docker-machine all the data i've added or modified are lost.
I've used this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/websphere-traditional/
on this docker registry there is also an image with the profile, do i need "a profile"? i'm new to websphere so i don't know exactly what is the role of the "profile" and if i need it

Comment: You must have at least one profile to use WAS, but when you docker run the image above, it creates one.  The install image already has once created, so you can use either.  Please edit your question to show the exact sequence and commands you're using, ie, after you docker run, what do you do, what command do you use to stop the WAS container.  When you say "switch off the docker machine", do you mean physically shutting down the host the docker container is running on or the container itself?

Comment: @F Rowe - i mean shutting down the host docker machine on Windows (the virtualbox virtual machine ) - [question edited]

Comment: For future SO questions, always describe key pieces of your env, like virtualbox, etc, those details matter.  A lot.  Of course you're losing your installed WAS applications, what did you think the 'docker rm test' was going to do?  Stop doing that.  Just do 'docker stop test'.  When you shutdown the virtualbox VM, just tell it to save the state of the VM and the next time you start it, just 'docker start test' and your applications will still be installed.